# how to add external jar file to a blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

How to add a third party jar file to a blackberry project in ECLIPSE SDK. When I am deploying the application to the device , it says "The module XXXX has verification errors". When I try to search in the internet , solutions exists for JDE(Webworks platform) but not for Eclipse plugin. Please suggest the procedure. Below are the steps I have done.

1. Download the 3rd party jar file
2. Preverify it using preverify.exe and used the verified JAR in my eclipse by adding to the build path.
3. Deployed to the device/simulator. (Surprisingly , It did n't signed the app )

Any ideas?

Comment: any errors showing, when you sign the app ?

Comment: No..... it's directly deploying into the device

Comment: which jar file you using ?

Comment: com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.jar


dowloaded from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomspringsourceorgobjectwebasm310jar.htm

Comment: Yes. Preverified By using preverify tool, and I had replaced that new JAR file with the existing one. But, still I'm getting these verification errors.

Comment: If you preverified using command line you would have to look for the preverified jar inside BBSDKPATH/bin directory. (I think preverify.exe creates an output directory there)

Comment: Yes. It creates preverified JAR there only. 
And I'm using the new JAR (I mean, the preverified JAR in output folder), but still I'm getting the ERROR !

Comment: May be the Jar file you are trying to attach have some Java API that doesn't supported by Blackberry. Do one thing Compile the Blackberry project and check ..is compiler give any warning ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this library (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomspringsourceorgobjectwebasm310jar.htm) can't be used in blackberry java projects - class "Type" from the library references some classes from java.lang.reflect package that are not available on BB